# Hibernate Could not parse mapping document from resource

Tags: hibernate

I know this has been asked a dozen times. I must be brain dead today as I've tried modifying my xml file a hundred ways and I can't figure it out.

Error stack when I run the driver:

```
16 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - Hibernate 3.3.2.GA
31 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - hibernate.properties not found
31 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - Bytecode provider name : javassist
31 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - using JDK 1.4 java.sql.Timestamp handling
78 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration - configuring from resource: test_hibernate/hibernate.cfg.xml
78 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration - Configuration resource: test_hibernate/hibernate.cfg.xml
125 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration - Reading mappings from resource : test_hibernate/contact.hbm.xml
Exception in thread "main" Could not parse mapping document from resource            test_hibernate/contact.hbm.xml
java.lang.NullPointerException
at test_hibernate.MyExample.main(MyExample.java:29)
```

Here's the MySQL code for how I built the table:

```
create database HibernateTest;
drop table contact;
Create table CONTACT(
ID int(15),
FIRSTNAME varchar(50) ,
LASTNAME varchar(50),
EMAIL varchar(150)); 
describe contact;
```

Here's my mapping file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="test_hibernate.Contact" table="CONTACT">
<id name="id" column="ID" >
<generator class="increment" />
</id>
<property name="firstName" column="FIRSTNAME" />
<property name="lastName" column="LASTNAME" />
<property name="email" column="EMAIL" />
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

And here's my config file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost/hibernatetest</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.username">###</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.password">###</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size">10</property>
  <property name="show_sql">true</property>
  <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
  <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
  <!-- Mapping files -->
  <mapping resource="test_hibernate/contact.hbm.xml"/>
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Any help is appreciated, thank you!!

Some additional information: Setup package test_hibernate and here's my persistence file:

```
package test_hibernate;
public class Contact {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;
    private long id;

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setEmail(String string) {
        email = string;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String string) {
        firstName = string;
    }

    public void setLastName(String string) {
        lastName = string;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long l) {
        id = l;
    }
}
```

and here's my driver:

```
package test_hibernate;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;

public class MyExample {

public static void main(String[] args) {
Session session = null;

try{
    // This step will read hibernate.cfg.xml and prepare hibernate for use
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();
    session=sessionFactory.openSession();
    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

    //Create new instance of Contact and set values in it by reading them from form object
    System.out.println("Inserting Record");

    Contact contact = new Contact();
    contact.setId(3);
    contact.setFirstName("Smitha");
    contact.setLastName("Rao");
    contact.setEmail("smithaxxx@yahoo.com");
    session.save(contact);
    tx.commit();
    System.out.println("Done");
}catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}finally{
    // Actual contact insertion will happen at this step

    session.flush();        
    session.close();
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your mapping file looks fine . I think it may due to you use **”** or **“** instead of **"** for the double quotations .Please try to use **"** for all the  double quotations.

Comment: oh no, really.. let me try. Thanks Ken. Had the ' vs MS Word's ' happen to me in SQL code before if that makes any sense.. Will check back

Comment: Yep, you nailed it. Updated the code above in my question. Everything should work for Hibernate 3.3 and MySQL for those who stumble across this post and need yet another example to try. I know it took me a number of goes before I had something even close.   Thank you Ken!

Answer (score 0):

does contact.hbm.xml and Contact POJO class exists in the same path?????

if not try giving package attribute like

```
<hibernate-mapping package="package name of Contact POJO class">
```

Comment: I didn't setup a package name for this test. Maybe it's required for hibernate to work?  Also yes the files are in the same path

Comment: Included the sql script used for building the table

Answer (score 0):

Put the port number of the MySQL connection that is **jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hibernatetest** in your configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

Your url should be `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hibernatetest`

Answer (score 0):

Please remove `<?xml version="1.0"?>` from your mapping file.It will solve your problem