# Hibernate : Failed to create sessionFactory object.org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, hibernate-mapping

I am sorry if this is a duplicate of any existing question. Following is my employee bean.

```
public class Employee {
       private int id;
       private String firstName; 
       private String lastName;   
       private int salary;  

       public Employee() {}
       public Employee(String fname, String lname, int salary) {
          this.firstName = fname;
          this.lastName = lname;
          this.salary = salary;
       }
       public int getId() {
          return id;
       }
       public void setId( int id ) {
          this.id = id;
       }
       public String getFirstName() {
          return firstName;
       }
       public void setFirstName( String first_name ) {
          this.firstName = first_name;
       }
       public String getLastName() {
          return lastName;
       }
       public void setLastName( String last_name ) {
          this.lastName = last_name;
       }
       public int getSalary() {
          return salary;
       }
       public void setSalary( int salary ) {
          this.salary = salary;
       }
    }
```

I want to map it to my postgres table employee

```
CREATE TABLE employee
(
  id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('emp_id_seq'::regclass),
  first_name character varying(20),
  last_name character varying(20),
  salary integer,
  CONSTRAINT employee_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

Here is my main Class code snippet

```
  try{
     factory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
  }catch (Throwable ex) { 
     System.err.println("Failed to create sessionFactory object." + ex);
     throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex); 
  }
```

while running it i get the following error

```
Failed to create sessionFactory object.org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Could not parse mapping document from resource Employee.hbm.xml
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at ManageEmployee.main(ManageEmployee.java:26)
Caused by: org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Could not parse mapping document from resource Employee.hbm.xml
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addResource(Configuration.java:575)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseMappingElement(Configuration.java:1593)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1561)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1540)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1514)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1434)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1420)
    at ManageEmployee.main(ManageEmployee.java:23)
```

Here is my mapping file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD//EN" "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd"> 
<hibernate-mapping package = "com.demo.hibernate.beans">
   <class name="Employee" table="employee">
      <meta attribute="class-description">
         This class contains the employee detail. 
      </meta>
      <id name="id" type="int" column="id">
         <generator class="native"/>
      </id>
      <property name="firstName" column="first_name" type="string"/>
      <property name="lastName" column="last_name" type="string"/>
      <property name="salary" column="salary" type="int"/>
   </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

What could be the possible reason i know this has something to do with Employee.hbm.xml. Please help

Thanks in advance !!!

Here is CFG File if it may help

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd"> 
<hibernate-configuration>
   <session-factory>
   <property name="hibernate.dialect">
      org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
   </property>
   <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">
      org.postgresql.Driver
   </property>

   <!-- Assume test is the database name -->
   <property name="hibernate.connection.url">
      jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres
   </property>
   <property name="hibernate.connection.username">
      postgres
   </property>
   <property name="hibernate.connection.password">
      postgres
   </property>

   <!-- List of XML mapping files -->
   <mapping resource="Employee.hbm.xml"/>

</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: @Do you have a hibernate.cfg.xml?

Comment: Is your Employee class under any package?

Comment: HBM CFG and classes are all under src folder

Comment: Why not retry putting it in a package?

Comment: As JtheRocker said try putting it in a package, and specify your package-name like this:
<hibernate-mapping package="your.package.name">
As it is under default package now, you might know classes in a default package are not accessible form outside.
So try putting it that way.

Comment: Now my HBM and CFG are in src and Main Class and Beans are under com.demo.hibernate.beans package. Had Updated my HBM as shown above

Comment: still doesnt solve my problem.

Comment: Somethings to test: 1. remove the type="" from each of the property in the the mapping file, let it resolve itself and 2. Try whatever is mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9913322/hibernate-could-not-parse-mapping-document-from-resource

Answer (score 1):

Error means Hibernate was unable to load mapping file (check code, is a wrap for a `FileNotFoundException`) so your error is in hibernate.cfg.xml file,not in mapping!
Check if `<mapping file="path/to/Employee.hbm.xml" />` is correct

Comment: HBM CFG and classes are all under src folder. So i guess it will not be needed

Comment: try /Employee.hbm.xml