# HibernateFactory class in hibernate will goes to exception case

Tags: java, web-services, hibernate

When we execute our project it goes to `catch (Exception e)`.

```
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.classic.Session;

public class HibernateFactory {

    private SessionFactory factory;
    private Configuration config;
    private Session session;

    /**
     * 
     * @return it will return session object. if session is not create then it
     *         will create otherwise return old session object.
     */

    public Session buildIfNeeded() {
        try {
            if (session != null) {

                return session;
            } else {
                config = new Configuration();
                config.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
                factory = config.configure().buildSessionFactory();
                session = factory.openSession();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            session.close();
        }
        return session;
    }

}
```

This is my hibernate.cfg.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM 
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">



<hibernate-configuration>
   <session-factory>
   <property name="hibernate.dialect">
      org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
   </property>
   <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">
      com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
   </property>

   <!-- Assume test is the database name -->
   <property name="hibernate.connection.url">
      jdbc:mysql://localhost/gauizzapplication
   </property>
   <property name="hibernate.connection.username">
      root
   </property>
   <property name="hibernate.connection.password">
      root
   </property>
      <property name="show_sql">true</property>
   <!-- List of XML mapping files -->
   <mapping resource="hbm/UserMaster.hbm.xml"/>
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

below is my error msg in consol:

```
org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Could not parse mapping document from resource hbm/UserMaster.hbm.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that `UserMaster.hbm.xml` is not good XML, try to run it through the IDE validator or an XML online validation tool such as [xmlvalidation.com](http://www.xmlvalidation.com/), also have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9913322/hibernate-could-not-parse-mapping-document-from-resource) for some causes.